# Replicating POST data taken from Fiddler in new POST

Tags: json, post

I am trying to replicate a post I have captured in Fiddler, I have one variable that is in what looks like JSON and I dont know how to replicate this in a POST string.

I have (from Fiddler):
{"var1":"string1", "params":{"1":"string2", "2":50, "3":50, "4":"string3"}, "var2":"string4"}

So my question is how do I represent the "params" variable in a POST url?

Currently I have ...[URL]?var1=string1&(PARAM STUFF)&var2=string4. What do I put in the PARAM STUFF place?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe you can add POST parameters in a url - you can do this for GET params, though. How exactly are you attempting to replicate the POST?

Comment: Its through a third party program that posts the data correctly, the string was more to illustrate what I was looking to achieve, which is the conversion of the param data into a usable string.

Comment: If the third party program posts the data correctly, I don't understand what the problem is. Do you want to replicate the data post in *another* way? If so, can you say how?